# Hypothesis in Hahn Banach's theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm studying my functional analysis textbook, but I don't understand some hypotheses about the Hahn-Banach's theorem.

I know that

**Real case:**

**Theorem 1.** Let $E$ be a real vector space and $p: E\to \mathbb{R}$ $\color{red}{\text{be a sublinear functional}}$. Let $W$ be a linear subspace of $E$. If $f: W\to \mathbb{R}$ is a linear functional such that $f(x)\leq p(x)$ for all $x\in W$, then there exists a linear functional $T: X\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $T(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in W$ and $T(x)\leq p(x)$ for all $x\in E$.

**Complex case:**

**Theorem 2.** Let $E$ be a vector space and $p: E\to \mathbb{R}$ $\color{red}{\text{a semi-norm}}$. Let $W$ be a linear suspace of $X$ and $f: W \to \mathbb{K}$ a linear functional. If $|f(x)|\leq p(x)$ for all $x\in W$, then there exists a linear functional $T: E\to \mathbb{K}$ extending $f$ such that $|T(x)|\leq p(x)$ for all $x\in E$.

I know that every semi-norm is a sublinear function and every real linear functional is a sublinear function. The converses are not true in general.

**Question 1:***What is the motivation for using the hypothesis of $p$ as a sublinear function in theorem 1 and not using the hypothesis of $p$ as a semi-norm directly?*

**Question 2:** *How is theorem 1 weakened if I change the hypothesis from sublinear to the semi-norm hypothesis?*

Any further explanation on the hypotheses would be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The main motivation is to be able to use $p$ equal the Minkowski functional of a convex set, which is sublinear. This is then used to proof all kind of separation theorems.

Note that Theorem 2 is also true for sublinear $p$, see, e.g.,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can we adapt a test where the hypothesis that p is a semi-norm is used to a test where p is a sublinear function? If this is the case, where do these hypotheses act differently in the theorem?

Comment: I don't see how to use the fact that p is a sublinear function and what a difference it makes when applying this hypothesis and not the semi-norm.

Comment: I dont understand either comment. What do you mean by 'test'? Also sublinearity is sufficient to prove Hahn-Banach in the complex case. So there is no difference...

Comment: I'm sorry. When I wrote «test» I was referring to «proof». On the other hand, I'm comparing the proof of theorem $1$ that I wrote in my post (here we have the hypothesisthat $p$ is sublinear function) with other proof about the theorem $1$ but with the hypothesis that $p$ is semi-norm. But, I don't see the difference in the proof about on those proof that differ in that hypothesis.

Comment: So, I'm worried about that I don't understand as the hypothesis with $p$ sublinear function and $p$ with semi norm function make a difference in both proofs.